# Duplicate name feature like file system

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do something like file system of our computer in which if file name "test" is presented in one folder and we try to create one more file with same name then we get result as "test(01)" and if we try again 
then we get the result "test(02)".

Basically, I want this kind of feature in my project. I am using mongoose and nodejs

```
// schema
var schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, options);
```

Whenever user added name in database i have to check if same name is already present then we append the count in its name.

Like first time user added name = test , then in db we will save as name = test

Second time added name = test, then in db we will save name as name = test(01)

Third time added name = test, then in db we will save name as name = test(02)

and so on like this.

Can anyone suggest help. Thanks !

Comment: This isn't trivial to implement. What's the exact problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, and describe to what extent it's succeeding or failing?

Comment: @robertklep : Above is an example of a problem which is i am facing in my project. I have explain exact problem below the schema.

Comment: @Sam but it's only part of the problem, because the way in which this may be implemented also depends on how exactly you intend to query these users (by original name or by modified name?), what should be done when a user enters `test(01)` as their username, if this is part of a login system, etc...

Answer (score 0):

you can add another fields as version and when a file comes check whether any earlier file is present with the same name or not if result is false/null then save as  a document else push as a version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough idea.

I would use regular expression to find all users having similar names, sort them descendingly, take the first result to know who was the user with highest suffix `(digit)` - in order to figure out the next digit. Our [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/uEd5Aj/1) will have one optional [capturing group](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) for `(digit)` part.

It would be something like this (bare in mind this is untested):

```
// suppose req.body.name = test

let re = new RegExp(`^${req.body.name}(\((.*)\))?$`, 'i'); // e.g. /^test(\((.*)\))?$/i

schema.find({ name: re }).sort('name', -1).limit(1).exec(function (err, users) {
    // there is a user with a similar name already
    if (users.length) {
        // apply regular expression on the matched user's name again to get info
        // about the capturing groups

        // note:
        // > re.exec('test')
        // > [ 'test', undefined, undefined, undefined, index: 0, input: 'test' ]
        // > re.exec('test(02)')
        // > [ 'test(02)', '(02)', '(02)', '(02)', index: 0, input: 'test(02)' ]

        let m = re.exec(users[0].name), digit = 0;
        // take out the number
        if (m && typeof m[1] !== 'undefined') {
            digit = parseInt(m[1].replace(/[^\w]/gi, ''), 10); // e.g. (02) => 2
        }
        let suffix = '(' + (++digit).toString().padStart(2, '0') + ')'; // e.g. 2 => (03)
        req.body.name += suffix;
    }
    schema.create(req.body, function () {
        // etc
    })
})
```

[Small illustration](https://repl.it/HTat/0)

Comment: In theory this is a nice solution, in reality it (and to be honest, every reasonably simple implementation) suffers from big concurrency issues.

Comment: You are right. It is a bigger problem than it seems.